# Parse shortcode with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I'm parsing a string like this with javascript:

```
[box style="a" width="b" height="c"]
```

So far, when I use http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ it works and it parses fine using this regex:

```
/(?<=\s).+?=".+?"/
```

However, when I do this in javascript it errors out:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=\s).+?=".+?"/:
>   Invalid group

This is part of the code:

```
if (scOpenTag instanceof Array) {
   var params = scOpenTag[0].match(/(?<=\s).+?=".+?"/);                    
   for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++)
      console.log(params[i]);
}
```

Somebody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple regex pattern

```
[\w-]+="[^"]*"
```

Comment: Yes, that dit it! Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind assertions; neither `(?<=...)` nor `(?<!...)` will work.

However, it looks like your keys/property-names/attribute-names/whatever-those-are have the form `\w+`, so you can get some mileage out of the word-boundary assertion `\b` (which matches either `(?<!\w)(?=\w)` or `(?<=\w)(?!\w)`):

```
/\b\w+="[^"]+"/
```

---

**Edited to add:** For that matter, you can get your *exact* current functionality by using a capture-group, and using `params[1]` instead of `params[0]`:

```
if (scOpenTag instanceof Array) {
   var params = scOpenTag[0].match(/\s(.+?=".+?")/);
   for (var i = 1; i < params.length; i++)
      console.log(params[i]);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, that's too bad. However, the params can also have space characters in them. So a string like [box style="metro action" url="http://www.someurl.com/"] would be applicable as well...

Comment: I see no reason to use `\b` in this case. If I am wrong, show me example of input where it makes difference.

Comment: @Ωmega: Perhaps you know more about "this case" than I do. I'm working based on what was in the question. The OP felt the need to use a lookbehind assertion; I wanted to offer something more than "drop it".